# Better one liner to generate n spaces

Tags: scala

Yes, its a fun question, but I want to learn to use the collections operations like map, reduce and fold correctly.

I did this:

```
scala> Range(0,3) map(_=>" ") reduceLeft(_+_)
res15: java.lang.String = "   "
```

What is a better, idiomatic way of generating n spaces with a collection operation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically the following is a "collection operation", I guess, since [`StringOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html) is in the `scala.collection.immutable` package:

```
scala> " " * 3
res1: String = "   "
```

What's happening here is that `" "` is implicitly converted to an instance of `StringOps` by [`scala.Predef.augmentString`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html), and then the `*` method on `StringOps` is called.

---

**Update:** I meant this partly as a kind of joke, since this clearly isn't what you meant by "collection operation"—it's not a higher-order function like `map` or `reduce`. I'd definitely use my version (the `StringOps` version) in real code, but if you wanted to use higher-order functions (for educational reasons, for a similar problem, etc.), I think your version is pretty close to idiomatic. I'd personally use `until` for building the range and `reduce` instead of `reduceLeft` (since concatenation is associative)—i.e., pretty much what virtualeyes has written in his or her answer.

Comment: nice one, did not think Scala did Ruby/Groovy but indeed it does ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Not as elegant as Travis solution, but imho the second most elegant way so far:

```
List.fill (3)(' ').mkString
```

Answer (score 2):

```
1 until 10 map (_=> " ") reduce(_+_)
```

is another perhaps more readable approach

Answer (score 1):

I think `foldLeft` is more proper:

```
Range(0,3).foldLeft("")((str, i) => str + " ")
```